# Sumar dos columnas en LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy tratando de sumar dos columnas desde una clase, pero las estoy manipulando con `LinQ` tengo entendido que se puede sumar pero no le encuentro, mi código es el siguiente le agredecería mucho su ayuda.

```
var Query = (from c in Conceptos.TablaConceptos
    select new TablaConcepto{
      ID = c.ID,
      FECHA = c.FECHA,
      REGION = c.REGION,
      ACTIVO = c.ACTIVO,
      INSTALACION = c.INSTALACION,
      TOTAL = c.TOTAL,
      EMPAQUE = c.EMPAQUE,
      QUEMADO = c.QUEMADO,
      INYECTADO = c.INYECTADO,
      ENDULZADO = c.ENDULZADO,
      AUTOCONSUMO = c.AUTOCONSUMO
  }).ToList();

return Query;`pudieran ayudar
```

Comment: se me paso lo que quier es que total contenga la suma de empaque, endulzado, inyectado, y demas, pero la idea es que esa consulta sea devuelta en un datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Como estas retornando una lista puedes usar la función [SUM()](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sum).
Exactamente no se quie quieres sumar, pero puedes aplicar para una sola propiedad.

```
var sumTotal = Query.Sum(s => s.TOTAL);
```

O puedes hacerlo con varias en la misma suma

```
var sumTotalConsumo  = Query.Sum(s => s.TOTAL + s.AUTOCONSUMO);
```

Pero si lo que buscas es por cada registro, sumalo desde que lo consultas.

```
var Query = (from c in Conceptos.TablaConceptos
                         select new TablaConcepto
                         {

                             ID = c.ID,
                             FECHA = c.FECHA,
                             REGION = c.REGION,
                             ACTIVO = c.ACTIVO,
                             INSTALACION = c.INSTALACION,
                             TOTAL = x.EMPAQUE + x.INYECTADO + x.ENDULZADO + x.AUTOCONSUMO,
                             EMPAQUE = c.EMPAQUE,
                             QUEMADO = c.QUEMADO,
                             INYECTADO = c.INYECTADO,
                             ENDULZADO = c.ENDULZADO,
                             AUTOCONSUMO = c.AUTOCONSUMO


                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: tengo esto pero fuera de la lista:

Comment: var total = Query.Sum(x => x.EMPAQUE + x.INYECTADO + x.ENDULZADO + x.AUTOCONSUMO);

Comment: ¿y te da el resultado que deseas?

Comment: la idea es que ese total sustituya o asigne el valor de lo sumano a TOTAL que esta en la lista , ya que estoy mostrando esos valores mediante un datasource

Comment: Es el total por cada registro o el total de todo?

Comment: total debe contener la suma de 5 elementos (empaque, inyectado, endulzado 
 . . .) y pasarlos a la lista como un elemento mas o asignarlo a TOTAL que ya esta en la lista

Comment: Entonces asignalo cuando defines el nuevo TablaConcepto

Answer (score 0):

Espero haber entendido tu requerimiento. Con la siguiente query obtienes, en TablaConcepto.Total la suma de los campos EMPAQUE, QUEMADO, INYECTADO, (puedes agregar o quitar). Es decir, obtienes el total de cada Item dentro del campo TOTAL, en la respuesta de @Aron Romero te explica como hacer la suma de todos los elementos que retornara la query.

```
var Query = (from c in Conceptos.TablaConceptos
             select new TablaConcepto
             {
                 ID = c.ID,
                 FECHA = c.FECHA,
                 REGION = c.REGION,
                 ACTIVO = c.ACTIVO,
                 INSTALACION = c.INSTALACION,
                 TOTAL = c.TOTAL + c.EMPAQUE + c.QUEMADO + c.INYECTADO,
                 EMPAQUE = c.EMPAQUE,
                 QUEMADO = c.QUEMADO,
                 INYECTADO = c.INYECTADO,
                 ENDULZADO = c.ENDULZADO,
                 AUTOCONSUMO = c.AUTOCONSUMO
             }).ToList();

            return Query;
```

Comment: ya lo intente de esa forma pero en la columna total en el datagridview no realiza la sumatoria

Comment: Entonces, en tu datagridview quieres obtener la sumatoria de esos campos, para todas las filas, o una suma por fila?

Comment: una suma por fila